# Modal image code doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to add some modal images to my website.

I used the code from W3Schools but it doesn't work. I have even used the code as it is to test if it works like that and nothing, the problem is the same.

This is the code i have used:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

The same code is working for me. Please find the working example link

```
Modal Image Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/sanoopjose/9x3vaofu/1/
```